# 12.04 won't recognize ethernet connection on my Toshiba Satellite

Tags: internet-connection, ethernet, toshiba

Like the title says, I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Satellite P875-S7200 and I can connect to the internet via wifi but my computer doesn't seem to recognize when I plug in a wired connection.  I know that there are no drivers on the Toshiba site that have anything to do with Linux as far as I can tell, and I have all the drivers for my windows partition (Which works flawlessly wired and wifi).  Is there something simple that I am not doing to help it recognize the ethernet connection?  Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Restart , and then connect a ethernet cable update, and install drivers. Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: It's the ethernet that's the problem, not wireless.  The machine probably doesn't even have the Broadcom wireless chips, so this advice is totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

The alx driver you probably need should be available in a later kernel than the default 12.04.  Any 13.xx release should work out of the box for ethernet.  You might try the 12.04.3 3.5.0 series kernel (the qualtal backports) linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal, linux-generic-lts-quantal, linux-image-generic-lts-quantal, and the quantal X server packages.